# What is the correct use of the || in javascript

Tags: javascript

In the code below, because  s  is null d = "test"
but if s = "hello" then d would = "hello".

Is this correct as it works? what is the correct way to use ||

```
var s = null;

var d = s || "test";

alert(d);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

|| is "or" ; and understanding what happens here is a bit trickery

```
var a=false;
var b=true;
result=a||b
```

will give "result" true (as b is true). What happens is:

- 'a' is checked - it is false
- 'b' is checked AFTERWARDS (as no "true" result has been obtained yet, and ONE "true" result would suffice to make the whole || operator be true) - the value of it will be assigned to the left side

if you had

```
   var a=true;
   var b="test";
   result=a||b
```

result will yield true; as no other value needs to be checked by the logic of "||"

with

```
var a=null;
var b="test";
result=a||b;
```

a will be checked first - it is null, which converts to "false".   b is "test", which is non-null, and converts to "true".  so the *value* of b will be assigned.

And yes, this is a correct way to use || ; the feature you use is also called short-circuit evaluation (as it stops evaluating the boolean expression as early as possible)

Answer (score 2):

This works, but if s evaluates to a 'falsy' value, you'll get your default, which might not be what you intended. A more robust, but wordy idiom is

```
d = (typeof s === "undefined") ? "test" : s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct unless s is allowed to be blank or 0 which are also falsy values

```
var s = null;
var d = s || "test";

var s = 0;
var d = s || "test";

var s = "";
var d = s || "test";
```

All will result in d being "test"

Answer (score 1):

`||` is a logical operator. When s is not null then the condition of (s) is true so d is assigned the value of s, otherwise it is assigned 'test'

Answer (score 1):

`||` is the `OR` operator in javascript
so `a||b` means `a OR b` in simple terms
explanation of question you have asked is that id you simply do somethings like these in js you will ultimately get in the else block

```
if(null)
if(undefined)
```

so `s||"test"` will mean which ever is not null or undefined
which in this case is test

Answer (score 1):

yes correct, || symbols just does the job of OR. when the first condition is true its gonna return that one.. else it will move to the next... simple as it is...